# LINQ not updating on .SubmitChanges()

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, submitchanges

Is there any reason something like this would not work?

This is the logic I have used many times to update a record in a table with LINQ:

```
 DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
 User updateUser = db.Users.Single(e => e.user == user);
 updateUser.InUse = !updateUser.InUse;
 db.Log = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\linq.log") { AutoFlush = true };
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

(updateUser.InUse is a bit field)

For some reason it isn't working. When I check the linq.log it is completely blank.

Could there be a problem with my .dbml? Other tables seem to work fine but I've compared properties in the .dbml and they all match.

It's as if the `db.SubmitChanges()`; does not detect any updates being required.

Comment: enjoy your Taxonomist on `submitchanges` :P

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The table could not be updated properly because it had no primary key. (Actually it had the column but the constraint was not copied when I did a SELECT INTO my dev table). **The DataContext class requires a primary key for updates.**

Comment: And mine.  I still make this mistake all these years later.  Just so easy to overlook, esp. when only one table has the issue.  Why is skeet's still on top? Too much rep?

Comment: Ug! I was fighting this all day until I found this comment. My table won't have a primary key... now back to the drawing board...

Answer (score 2):

Is the InUse property a "normal" one as far as LINQ is concerned? (e.g. it's not autogenerated or anything funky like that?)

Alternatively, I don't suppose it's a Nullable<bool> is it, with a current value of null? If so, your update line isn't actually doing anything - for nullable Booleans, !null = null.

Comment: updateUser.InUse = !updateUser.InUse;

is not the problem. it is not nullable and i've tried hardcoding both false and true.

it is not auto generated.