# LINQ to SQL: SubmitChanges() does not work?

Tags: c#, database, linq, linq-to-sql

Here's my code

```
var bt = new BachtuocvnDataContext();
        var matchedTeams = (from lt in bt.Bet_Leagues_Teams
                         where lt.LeagueID == leagueID
                         select (lt)).Single();
        matchedTeams.TeamID = teamID;
        bt.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);
```

It does not update the table. Traditional query works well, I found a similar question here:

[LINQ not updating on .SubmitChanges()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206532/linq-not-updating-on-submitchanges)

but I checked and found that Bet_Leagues_Teams does have a primary key.

Bet_Leagues_Teams class:

```
int ID (primary key)
int LeagueID;
int TeamID;
```

Ahhhh, MY TERRIBLE MISTAKE. I forgot that Bet_Leagues_Teams may not contains the record needed. I must check if the record existed, and then update it, or it does not exist and I must add it to the table. Shame on me. Forgive me for wasting your time. Thank you.

Comment: So what's the primary key of Bet_League_Teams? Also, why are you setting `matchedTeams.ID` to itself?

Comment: @Jon: I edited my question, added more details and fixed some typos.

Comment: out of interest, can you confirm if the matchedTeams instance contains a primary key value? ie. the ID property has a value? What are the two values of matchedTeams.TeamID (after the data has been retrieved) and the value of teamID?

Answer (score 1):

```
using(BachtuocvnDataContext bt = new BachtuocvnDataContext() ) 
{ 
    Bet_Leagues_Teams matchedTeam = 
        bt.Bet_Leagues_Teams.Where(lt => lt.LeagueID == leagueID)
        .SingleOrDefault(); 

    if(matchedTeam != null)
    {
        matchedTeam.TeamID = teamID; 
        bt.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnClonflict); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using( var bt = new BachtuocvnDataContext() )
{
    var matchedTeam = bt.Bet_Leagues_Teams.Single( lt => lt.LeagueID == leagueID );
    matchedTeam.TeamID = teamID;
    bt.SubmitChanges( ConflictMode.ContinueOnClonflict );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, its essentially the same as your example after your edit.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `Single()` will throw an exception if there is more than one matching elements (which, if your schemea models the concept of "league" properly, there will be)

You may want to use `First()` there.