# Records not updating in linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Below is my common method to **insert** and **update** record,insert is working fine but *update* is not working for the below:

**Code:**

```
Public void Save(Employee e)
{
 using (var context = new SchoolManagementDataContext())
   {
      if(e.id > 0)  //For Update Part
      {
         var data=context.Employee.FirstorDefault(x=>x.EmployeeId==e.eid);
         data.Employeename=e.name;
         //rest other fileds to update.
         context.SubmitChanges();
      }
      else
      {
         context.Employee.InsertonSubmit(e);
         context.SubmitChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

I don't know why, but records are not getting updated.

Comment: Can you launch the sql profiler and see if\what sql statement has been issued?

Comment: When you filter data by **ID** make an habit of using `SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstorDefault`, `SingleOrDefault` is commonly used when **ID** is a primary key. You have bought model `Employee e` as parameter so in `If..Else` clause this must be `e.id` not `employee.id`

Comment: @SuprabhatBiswal:yeah i have updated my question according to that but still issue is record is not updating

Comment: Is Employee a model of the database table?  It seems odd that you're using different variables names: `data.Employeename=e.name;`.  Have you debugged to verify that a valid Employee record is being returned (the `data` variable)?

Comment: Yes Employee is model of database table and yes i have debug that valid employee is being returned in data variable

Answer (score 1):

I think, you need UpdateOnSubmit() method. Try this:

```
Public void Save(Employee e)
{
 using (var context = new SchoolManagementDataContext())
   {
      if(e.id != null)  //For Update Part
      {
         var data=context.Employee.FirstorDefault(x=>x.EmployeeId==e.eid);
         data.Employeename=e.name;
         //rest other fileds to update.
         context.Employee.UpdateOnSubmit();
         context.SubmitChanges();
      }
      else
      {
         context.Employee.InsertonSubmit(e);
         context.SubmitChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

UpdateOnSubmit:

```
     public virtual void UpdateOnSubmit(T Entity)
     {
        myEntities.Attach(Entity);
        context.Entry(Entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
     }
```

Comment: There is no such method available:UpdateOnSubmit

Comment: I am not using entity framework.I am using linqtosql so this method attach is not available in linqtosql

Comment: Oh, sorry man. Maybe you can control this post[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206532/linq-not-updating-on-submitchanges]. I recognize to very common  this update error.